# Scala type annotations on right side?

Tags: scala

In scala if I have a declaration such as this:

```
val i: Float = 5
```

Is this the same like in this line:

```
val i = 5: Float
```

?

Recently I encountered an expression  with such type annotation on the right side and I wonder what its usage is as I could not find it in the specs.

Comment: I would make an assumption that in first case you defining a value as Float. In the second case you assigning value of 5 which is Float to value i. The good example would be if you would try convert 5: Float to your own custom type. So you will be in the situation where you have to define impilict converter etc.

Comment: In both cases, you get a float-variable with the value 5.0. At least in this example they are equal, independent of what happens in the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called **type ascription** and it's meant to disambiguate types when several options might be available.

A typical example is a fold:

```
val l = 1 to 5
val stringyfied = l.foldLeft(Nil)((list, elem) => elem.toString :: list)
```

What is the type of `Nil` in that case? If you try that example, the compile will bark with an error:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : List[String]
required: scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type
```

We can make the specific type known to the compiler by using **type ascription**:

```
val stringyfied = l.foldLeft(Nil:List[String])((list, elem) => elem.toString :: list)
// stringyfied: List[String] = List(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

Another common use is to view a collection as a vararg as in:

```
def varargs(a:Int*) = a.sum
// common use:
varargs(1,2,3,4,5) //15

// now we have a collection of elements: 
val intlist = 1 to 5
// we cannot call varagrs with a list
varargs(intlist)
> found   : List[Int]
> required: Int

// then using type ascription:
varargs(intlist: _*)
```

To my knowledge, there's not much specific documentation about type ascription other than the specification of the algebra of expressions [SLS#Chapter6](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

This syntax is used to assign types to expressions (while `val i: Float = 5` assigns a type to a term). It can make a difference when you do it with a part of a bigger expression.

```
scala> implicit class WeirdFloat(f: Float) {
     |   def +(ff: Float) = new WeirdFloat(f + ff * 2)
     |   override def toString = s"$f"
     | }
defined class WeirdFloat

scala> val i: WeirdFloat = 5 + 7
i: WeirdFloat = 12.0

scala> val i = (5: WeirdFloat) + 7
i: WeirdFloat = 19.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the only difference is that the type of `i` is inferred (by the compiler) from the value in the second example, whereas in the first you are being explicit about the type of `i`.

The [stye guidelines](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html) encourage the use of type of inference wherever possible. However, [it also mentions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#ascription) that the syntax whereby you follow the value with the type is the approach when you are using ascription - a compile time upcast.

```
scala> val s = "Jane"
s: String = Jane

scala> val p = s: Object
p: Object = Jane
```